# Reroute request between 2 nginx servers if either is down

Tags: nginx, load-balancing

I have two Nginx servers  (A.mydomain.com) and (B.mydomain.com). I am trying to achieve a DR setup before I want to start work on it, I have few questions.
I have a kind of idea to, place new Nginx server in front of (A.mydomain.com) and (B.mydomain.com) to the proxy.
I am exploring other options, We don't have the budget for Cloudflare, Akamai, or Netscaler

1) Can we set up a backup like?
If A.mydomain.com (the server itself) goes down.. all request should go to B.mydomain.com and user will get a response if it has come from A.mydomain.com
and 
if B.mydomain.com goes down all request should now go to A.mydomain.com

2) If yes, Where and which file I should start

3) If not, How do I achieve this with free software?

Comment: You're looking for a load balancer, and there are many to choose from.

Comment: You could consider DNS round robin load balancing. I'm not sure how effective it is for failover. A load balancer would work, but if it's a piece of hardware rather than a service it's another single point of failure. This is why using CloudFlare or similar is valuable. Nginx and HAProxy are software load balancers, you could see if either support clustering - I have no idea if they do or not.

Comment: @Tim Thanks for replying to me on this topic. As you suggested I will continue to explore options on DNS based load balancing.

Comment: @MichaelHampton - Agreed, I guess Global load balancer may help me on this. I will explore. Thank you for replying.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your approach is correct. You could configure a third (smaller) NGINX server that `proxy_pass` between both servers. There are [several strategies](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/load_balancing.html) you can use. I would use an `ip_hash` strategy, combined with giving the main server (i.e. A.mydomain.com) more [weight](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html) in order to force requests going there first. Also, implement a health check so you can check whether a server is up or not.